# mod_rewrite: how to write a correct rule to redirect from long to short URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite

We have different rewrite rules in .htaccess, which look like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^view-([_a-zA-Z]+)-([_a-zA-Z]+)$  /controllers/index.php?action=$1|$2
```

We need to create a mirror rewrite condition for some of our rewrite rules, which would do a 301 redirect from long URL to short URL. E.g.

```
RewriteRule ^controllers/index\.php\?action=([_a-zA-Z]+)\|([_a-zA-Z]+)$  /view-$1-$2 [R=301]
```

However, by some reason this rule doesn't work. Can you please help us to understand why?

Thank you.

UPDATE: We had tried a lot of different escape sequences, but none seem to work for us

Comment: what url you have and what url you want?

Comment: @SunnyTAR - I want the requests that come to /controllers/index.php?action=one|two to be 301 redirected to /view-one-two

Comment: Try to put `/` in `RewriteRule ^/controllers/index...`

Comment: @SunnyTAG: we have tried that - doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had found the solution.

First of all, we didn't well understand how mod_rewrite works - the RewriteRule cannot parse the query string.
For that it is necessary to add a rewrite condition, which will parse the query string and then the rewrite rule, which will use the parsed query string.

So, to resolve our situation we have needed the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    ^action=([_a-zA-Z]+)\|([_a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^controllers/index\.php$    /view-%1-%2?    [R=301,L]
```

Note, that the parameters parsed by RewriteCond are referenced then through %, not through $.
Also, note that to bypass passing of the query string to the result rule we're using the ? in the end of the target path.

Now the only thing left is to get rid of cyclic redirects, but that's the different story.